# Where can I find images of ancient middle eastern cities and towns?

Tags: stock-images

Ancient cities and towns get recreated a lot in games but I am hoping to find some images, illustrations, composites to use in a video. I realize they will have to be recreations but I am not looking for current images of dilapidated structures.

Take for instance, Assassin's Creed, a ton of ancient buildings and cities. Is there anywhere to buy anything like that?

Thanks

Comment: The stuff you see in games is painted using photos as a general reference guidelines. Seeing as the camera wasn't invented until the 1800s it's doubtful you'll find photos of full cities. Illustrations may be a possibility, but I'd wager they would be fairly pricey. You could try finding photos of older middle eastern cities today. They may get close.

Comment: I'm just wondering if artwork similar to that used in games is available for purchase as stock images. Paying for illustrations is not feasible and I don't want ruins. Thanks though.

Comment: It's possible it's available via stock agencies, but it would seem to have a very limited market. As such, this question is essentially just asking us to do research for you.

Comment: @DA01. No. Don't research. If you know, great. If you don't, don't worry about it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[Shutterstock's fantasy category](http://www.shutterstock.com/s/fantasy/search.html) has some nice images you might be able to use (or if you find a style you like you can contact the artist directly). I'd also consider navigating through a site like [DeviantArt](http://www.deviantart.com/), where young artists showcase they work. Commissions are usually not that pricey.

You could also search for stock videos / footage, it's quite specific but some libraries can be huge, so it's worth a try (especially the 3D ones).

Some sites you might want to check:

- [iStock Video](http://www.istockphoto.com/video)
- [Shutterstock Footage](http://footage.shutterstock.com/)
- [Getty Images Footage](http://www.gettyimages.co.nz/footage)
- [Revostock](http://www.revostock.com/)
- [Videoblocks](http://www.videoblocks.com/videos/) (free)
- [3D Footage](http://www.3dfootage.com/)

I'd also consider asking 3D artists directly, too. Depending on the complexity, they could generate some simple images or animations for you, or point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

What about using googles ketchup, the 3d models used on earth, as a starting point?

Comment: I find ketchup makes a mess of my workstation. :)

Comment: that's probably the best approach at this time. thanks